# How do I find the number of video games with more than 5 developers. (SQL query)

Tags: sql, mariadb

Lets say i have 2 tables which are videogames and developers.

Under the videogames table, we have the following attributes:

- videogameid(PK)
- title
- dateOfRelease

Under the developer table, we have attributes:

- developerid(PK)
- name
- position

I tried finding the total number of videogames that had more than 5 developers. Here is my attempt to resolve the issue.

```
SELECT COUNT(videogameid)
FROM videogames, developers
WHERE videogameid = developerid
GROUP BY developerid
HAVING COUNT(developerid) > 5;
```

While I did not get any error issues but no results popped up.The result was null and not even zero.Hence i might have done something wrong.

EDIT: Yes there is one more table that actually relates to them it was videogames2developers which has the following attributes:

```
-videogameid
-developerid
-genre
```

Comment: SQL Server <> MySql, but you've tagged both.

Comment: To me it looks like you are missing at least one table like `works_on` or something similar that connects developers and games.

Comment: Why are `videogameid` and `developerid` related?

Comment: oh okay yes there is one more table that I forgot to mention which was videogames2developers which has the attributes:

-videogameid
-developerid
-genre

Comment: So add that table information to your question

Comment: Hello, you need a third table to map the many to many relationship between game and dev. https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-handle-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-datab

Comment: Yes i have already mentioned that in the question under the edited section. Both the videogameid and developerid are foreign keys in that table

Comment: Tip of today: Use the modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: With "modern" jarlh means the syntax that has been used in the last thirty years. Comma-separated joins are a thing of the 1980s mainly.

Comment: Why is there a genre column in the table videogames2developers? Does one game have several genres and each is developed by another person? To me the column looks kind of dislocated in the table.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? I see from the comments above that you tagged two different DBMS, and the tags got removed hence. With SQL requests it is often essential to know the DBMS they relate to.

Comment: Im using mysql(mariaDB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bridge table videogames2developers suffices for this task. First get all video games with more than five developers, then count how many these are.

```
select count(*)
from
(
  select videogameid
  from videogames2developers 
  group by videogameid
  having count(*) > 5
) games_with_more_than_five_devs;
```

This assumes that there is one entry per game and developer in the table. If this is not the case, then replace `having count(*) > 5` by `having count(distinct developerid) > 5`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join `videogames2developers` with `videogames` and `developers` table:

```
select count(videogameid) 
from
    (SELECT v.videogameid
    FROM videogames v inner join videogames2developers vd
         on v.videogameid =vd.videogameid 
                      inner join developers d
         on vd.developerid=d.developerid
    GROUP BY v.videogameid
    HAVING COUNT(d.developerid) > 5
) t
```

Comment: True, but this is a comment. Its certainly not an answer

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly .I have revised my answer.

Comment: Hi, you have the idea right. However, instead of your answer, I used 
`SELECT COUNT(v.videogameid)'

v.title is irrelevant since I do not want the title of the game but even after using the COUNT function. I end up getting answers where they show the number of developers working for each videogame which exceeds 5. However, all I wanted was to find the number of video games that had more than 5 developers working on it. For example, I have 7 different videogames and out of 7 only 4 of them have more than 5 developers working on them. Hence answer should be 4

Comment: @DaddySinged got your point. You can use an outer query to count the videogameid which have at least 5 developers.

Comment: Hi do you mind telling me what does the letter 't' represents at the end of the query?

Comment: It's an alias. Just like `videogames v`.

Comment: hmm for some reason , i had a syntax error running this query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242517/discussion-between-daddysinged-and-kazi-mohammad-ali-nur).